# SSL certificate does not exist or is empty Xampp

Tags: apache, xampp, windows-10, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to get https up and running with Xampp v3.2.2 running on windows 10.

I used letsencrypt-win-simple v1.9.3 to generate the certificates and that  was succesfull.

All three Certificate files are made:

- SSLCertificateFile
- SSLCertificateKeyFile
- SSLCertificateChainFile

are made and the all start with:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

and end with:

-----END CERTIFICATE-----

In the VirtualHost part of my httpd-ssl.conf i have the following:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

ServerAdmin ******@gmail.com
ServerName home.mywebsite.nl

RewriteEngine On
# Redirect to the correct domain name
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^home.mywebsite.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://home.mywebsite.nl/$1 [NE,L,R=301]

Alias /.well-known C:/xampp/htdocs/.well-known

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "C:/Users/<**user**>/AppData/Roaming/letsencrypt-win-simple/httpsacme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/home.mywebsite-crt.pem"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Users/<**user**/AppData/Roaming/letsencrypt-win-simple/httpsacme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/home.mywebsite.nl-key.pem"
SSLCertificateChainFile "C:/Users/<**user**/AppData/Roaming/letsencrypt-win-simple/httpsacme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/ca-<**hex**>-crt.pem"
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite...
```

After this i try to start up appache but get an error. When running this

C:\xampp\apache\bin>httpd in cmd i get the following error:

```
c:\xampp\apache\bin>httpd
AH00526: Syntax error on line 134 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf:
SSLCertificateFile: file 'C:/Users/<**user**>/AppData/Roaming/letsencrypt-win-simple/httpsacme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/home.mywebsite-crt.pem' 
does not exist or is empty
```

Can anyone help me out whit this?